# How to add a clickTAG function on AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, clicktag

I have this banner that has 3 tabs that would require clickTAGs added to the buttons of each tab section.  Currently, the banner works fine with the code attached, but when I try to insert a clickTAG function, everything gets screwy and I end up having a blinking banner. I hope someone here can help me out.

This is the code that I am using:

```
this.btn_launchsite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f);
function f(e:MouseEvent) : void {
   navigateToURL(new URLRequest ("http://kpmginfo.com/cfo/"),"_blank");
}
```

I tried adding this between the void { and navigateToURL:

```
var click_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG;
    if(click_url) {
```

And this made the whole banner blinking.

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure entirely what your are trying to achieve ie. do you want to track clicks? within flash? send tracking data to an external php?     either way I would firstly created your clickTag function outside your click button function & then call the clickTag function from within the click banner function.

eg. something like.

```
var URL_Tag = 0;
function ClickTagger (e:Event=null):void {root.URL_Tag = root.URL_Tag + 1;}

this.btn_launchsite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickBanner);
function ClickBanner (event:MouseEvent) : void {
   navigateToURL(new URLRequest ("http://kpmginfo.com/cfo/"),"_blank");
   ClickTagger();
}

trace (URL_Tag); // this line is for testing and debugging.
```